# Is "nor" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is used in an academic paper and I would like to know if it is correct

> Ultrasound showed no abnormalities nor signs of myopericarditis.

Comment: What are your doubts?

Comment: I believe the OP is confused if _nor_ occurs only in conjunction with _neither_ or if it can be used like here as well. But it is perfectly valid to use _nor_ like this.

Comment: Yes, but I would use "The ultrasound" as I doubt you mean the technique. You are referring to a specific one.

Comment: Though I would seldom (if ever) disagree with Lambie, I think the sentence fits medical parlance adequately without the definite article. (Although I have little medical education, I write as one who has made substantial contributions to the profession.)

Comment: @RonaldSole In a formal paper, the article is needed. On a medical chart, it would not be. Think about it.

Comment: @Lambie We are agreed.

Comment: @RonaldSole Great minds.....:)

Comment: As a professional editor, I (and my present colleagues) would tend to defer to the author on "Ultrasound showed..." in a medical context, and the journal editors generally concur (based on the editor responses I see). "The ultrasound" here would imply that the paper previously described this diagnostic process and is referring to it again. This convention really seems to irritate some, but it's concise and unambiguous and widely accepted. "Ultrasound" here refers to ultrasound inspection (or observation or characterization or testing).

Comment: "The ultrasound showed ..." (or "An ultrasound showed ...") implies a specific instance of an application of the technique.  That is, you performed an ultrasound (once) and the results of that one test are what you are referring to.  However, "Ultrasound showed ..." implies simply that *ultrasound procedures* were used to determine something, and does not refer to a specific instance or application, so these two terms actually mean two different things (and are not necessarily interchangeable).